# How to Change User Control to Another User Control in UltraTab?

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics

UltraTabControl in the Form. UltraTabControl has several Tabs. Each tab assigns each TabPageControl. Each TabPageControl was added using Form Designer.

Each page has a User Control assigned to it. In User Control called A, I want to open User Control called B, using a function.

I tried, but B does not open and stays at A.
Below is the code I tried.

Function in From,

```
public void Open_B()
    {
        uTabMain.SelectedTab = uTabMain.Tabs["B"];
        customArgs = new ItemEventArgs(uExplorerBar.Groups[9].Items["B"]);
        uExplorerBar_ItemClick(uExplorerBar, customArgs);
    }
```

Use Function in A,

```
Form.Open_B();
```

What should I do?

I am sorry that my English is not good.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to understand what you want.

To change Tabs for infragistics--

In VB:

```
 Me.uTabMain.Tabs("B").Selected = True
```

Ill correct this part but I think C# would be

```
Me.uTabMain.Tabs["B"].Selected = True;
```

Comment: Sorry for you hard to understand. I want to change the tab page assigned to the explorer bar in the main form from User Control assigned to tab page. I tried this code.... T.T But, same result.....T.T...

Comment: I solved it by using thread..!! Thank you for your attention :D